# Response should have any of two given properties

Tags: json, node.js, mocha.js, chai

I am Writing testcases for response received using Chai.

response we received is in the form of json object.

It should throw error if any of keys ('result' or 'results') contains in the json object.

if anyone of the above keys is present, it should not throw any error.

like  ----  respone.body.should.have.property('result' or 'results');

Comment: please show some code that you have tried.

Comment: It's not a JSON object, it's a JavaScript object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Chai expect `.any` and `.all` properties. See examples below:

```
expect(response.body).to.contain.any.keys('result', 'results');
expect(response.body).to.contain.all.keys('result', 'results');
```